# Java generics with upper bound

Tags: java, generics, spring-security, wildcard

Say I have following sample application, I'm using java 8.

I have following class that has a child class:

```
public class GrantedAuthority { }
public class GrantedAuthoritySubClass extends GrantedAuthority { }
```

Following class is where the tricky part happens:

```
public class UserDetails {

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

My main method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDetails u = new UserDetails();
        List<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        list.add(new GrantedAuthoritySubClass());
        u.getAuthorities().addAll(list);
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Error:(12, 35) java: incompatible types: `java.util.List<GrantedAuthority>` cannot be converted to `java.util.Collection<? extends capture#1 of ? extends GrantedAuthority>`

My problem is, how I can pass a collection of `GrantedAuthoritySubClass` Objects to the collection returned by `u.getAuthorities()`. I can't figure it out and there are so many compilation errors attached to various ways I've tried.

Comment: what the point of having wildcard in your example ? take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?rq=1

Comment: @JEY This is about spring-security 4.0.3 and UserDetails class in spring structured like above. I just wanted to make the question simpler without mentioning that.

Comment: just return Collection<GrantedAuthority> i don't see the point of having a wildcard.

Comment: @JEY Can you please assume that, wild card is there and its not changeable. What should be the solution then.

Comment: Ok it's part of the clientdetails interfaces. My bad. I'm affraid that if you want to add authority you have to create your own method in you UserDetails implementation.

Comment: check my answer it should fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) is an interface for spring security you can't change the method definition. You can't add [GrantedAuthority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) with your method. However in the implementation you can override the getAuthorities to return a collection that match the interface definition:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new  ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

And now you can use it like this:

```
UserDetailsImpl u = new UserDetailsImpl();
u.getAuthorities().add(new GrantedAuthority());
```

It's also possible to use your own GrantedAuthority type like this:

```
public class MyGrantedAuthority extends GrantedAuthority{

}

public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private Collection<MyGrantedAuthority> authorities = new  ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<MyGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
}


UserDetailsImpl u = new UserDetailsImpl();
u.getAuthorities().add(new MyGrantedAuthority());
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) rule, your `authorities` collection is a `producer` of elements (since it uses extends). This means that the collection can only "produce" or "output" `GrantedAuthority` objects or its subclasses. It also means you can't put anything into the collection since you don't know the collection's *actual* type.

If you used `super` you could put your objects there (but you couldn't get them out), but I suspect that the wildcard is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can't compile cause you don't know what kind of Collection you get.

You need to change the signature to

```
Collection<? super GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
```

This illustrates the problem (c) [Andrey Tyukin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707792/andrey-tyukin):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You try to be too exact using the wildcard (and get yourself into generics-hell that way.)

Basically, try to avoid wildcards and use natural inheritance when possible. In your example, alter your UserDetails as follows:

```
public class UserDetails {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

... and all will be fine. Especially, you can add an instance of GrantedAuthoritySubClass, as natural inheritance kicks in.